# Charge in atoms in bond

Tags: charge, atomic-physics, physical-chemistry, ions

Let us think of a covalent bond between two atoms $A$ and $B$. Since in covalent bond,sharing of electrons take place, valence eletrons of one atom behave as the electrons of the other atom. So since $A$ gets $B$'s share of electrons, it's electron number has increased more than before. If the atomic number of $A$ is $x$,now proton number of $A$ is $x$ and electron number is $x+$ something,so number of electron is more than proton and as such w.r.t $A$, $A$ develops negative charge. Similarly $B$ develops negative charge. But we know there is no charge formed in covalent bond. So where is my misconception?

Comment: This is just a mess… electrons are being ripped away like marbles in bonding. They are being smeared out in such a way that their probability density is built up in between the atoms that are bound together.

Comment: You start out with overall neutrality and end with -2. The basic accountancy is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

In a covalent bond, there is no complete transfer of electrons as you have suggested, and that is the reason why there is no net charge. Electrons are being equally *shared* and the bond forms an electron cloud that is distributed symmetrically between the nuclei.

But when we consider [electronegativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativity), uneven partial charge can develop in covalent bonds. This occurs because there can be shifting of the electron clouds towards an atom that has greater electronegativity.

But as stated, there is no *net* electrical charge when you look at the whole molecule because of the even sharing of electrons.